# Total result for PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form built with checkboxes but I am unable to calculate the total result for it. I want to get the total if user selects three checkboxes total will be $3 if one then $1. I am stuck as I am unable to do the calculation.

```
<html 
<head>
    <title>Order</title>

</head>
<body>


<link rel= "stylesheet" href= "order.css">
<form action="complete.php" method="post">
<form name="order">
<fieldset><legend>Complete Order:</legend>
<h1> Choose Design </h1>
<p><label>Your Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
<label>Address: <input type="text" name="address"></label>
    <label>Credit Card #: <input type="text" name="creditcard"></label>
    <label>Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker" name='date' size='9' value="" > </label>


<br><label> Design Types: <img src="1.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="1"></label> $1.00 
<label><img src="2.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="2"> </label>$1.00
<label><img src="3.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="3"> </label>$1.00

<br></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order"> 
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Php code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    if ( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['creditcard']) ) {
        echo "<p>Thank you, <strong>{$_POST['name']}</strong>, for placing the order. 
        <p>Your item will be shipped to: 
        <tt>{$_POST['address']}</tt></p>
        <p>Following credit card has been charged: <em>{$_POST['creditcard']}</em>.</p>\n";





    } else { //Missing form value.
        echo '<p>Please go back and fill out the form again.</p>';
    }


?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use `isset` to check which values you are getting in the php code.

Answer (score 1):

Changes in HTML:

```
<label><img src="1.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="fieldname[]" value="1"></label> $1.00 
<label><img src="2.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="fieldname[]" value="1"> </label>$1.00
<label><img src="3.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="fieldname[]" value="1"> </label>$1.00
```

PHP Code: it will count number of selected checkboxes-

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['fieldname']) && !empty($_POST['fieldname'])){
    echo count($_POST['fieldname']);  //count the number of selected checkbox
    echo array_sum($_POST['fieldname']); //sum of selected checkbox values
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's about checkbox's name. If they are a group of values (e.g: products), use a common name as an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" />
```

The second question, shouldn't your checkbox has a value or it'll be always $
1.00?

It it'll be always $1.00, just count it:

```
$value = isset($_POST['product']) ? count($_POST['product']) : 0;
```

If it should has a value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="1.00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="1.50" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="2.00" />
```

Can use the [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function:

```
$value = isset($_POST['product']) ? array_sum($_POST['product']) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset($_POST['checkboxName'])` to check if the checkbox is checked and then add 1 for each checkbox:

```
$check_value = 0;
$check_value += isset($_POST['1']) ? 1 : 0;
$check_value += isset($_POST['2']) ? 1 : 0;
$check_value += isset($_POST['3']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the php part:

```
<?php
    if ( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['creditcard']) ) {
        $cost = 0;
        if(isset($_POST['1'])) $cost += 1;
        if(isset($_POST['2'])) $cost += 1;
        if(isset($_POST['3'])) $cost += 1;
        echo "<p>Thank you, <strong>{$_POST['name']}</strong>, for placing the order. 
        <p>Your item will be shipped to: 
        <tt>{$_POST['address']}</tt></p>
        <p>Following credit card has been charged: <em>{$_POST['creditcard']}</em>.</p>
        <p>With amount: <em>{$cost}</em>.</p>\n";
    } else { //Missing form value.
        echo '<p>Please go back and fill out the form again.</p>';
    }
?>
```